# Implementing SearchView to RecyclerView with cards, need help toubleshooting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Context: I am using a RecyclerView with cards that displays information from Firebase Realtime database. I am trying to implement a SearchView sucth that the RecyclerView gets filtered

However, the RecyclerView is not getting filtered after inputting stuff into the search bar. Need some help troubleshooting please, code builds fine with no errors.

**Adapter code**

```
public class sessionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<sessionAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Session> list;
    ArrayList<Session> listFiltered;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private FilterActivity activityFilter;

    public sessionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Session> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.session,parent,false);
        return  new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Session user = list.get(position);
        holder.activity.setText(user.getActivity());
        holder.location.setText(user.getLocation());
        holder.time.setText(user.getTime());
        holder.pax.setText(user.getPax());
        holder.currpax.setText(user.getCurrPax());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener() {
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView activity, location, time, pax,currpax;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            activity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvActivity);
            location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvtime);
            pax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvpax);
            currpax = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvcurrpax);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            mListener.onItemClick(position);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(activityFilter == null)
            activityFilter = new FilterActivity(this, list);
        return activityFilter;
    }

}
```

**Filter code**

```
public class FilterActivity extends Filter {
    private sessionAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<Session> list;
    ArrayList<Session> filteredList;

    public FilterActivity(sessionAdapter mAdapter, ArrayList<Session> list) {
        super();
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
        this.list = list;
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint.length() == 0 || constraint == null) {
            filteredList.addAll(list);
        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (final Session item : list) {
                if (item.getActivity().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults (CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
        mAdapter.listFiltered.clear();
        mAdapter.listFiltered.addAll((ArrayList<Session>) results.values);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Main Activity portion**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Your `sessionAdpater` works on `list` array list and not on `listFiltered` . But after filtering the result you have updated the result in  `mAdapter.listFiltered.addAll((ArrayList<Session>) results.values);` . Shouldn't it be `mAdapter.list` to reflect the changes ,

Comment: @Nitish Ah yes thank you that solved the issue! On a side note, the filter doesn't seem to be working as intended, for example, if I have Soccer as my activity, when I input 'So' no results seem to show up. Do you have any idea where it may have gone wrong? Works fine for some other activities though..

Comment: Try to attach debug `if (item.getActivity().contains(filterPattern))` and see if , `if condition` satisfy when you search So,.

Comment: Yup that was the error! Forgot to add a .toLowerCase() right there. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Glad I could be of help